# MySQL SELECT and then save or update to a different table when special characters are in the first table. leave_my_text_alone();

Tags: php, mysql, regex, escaping

I have text correctly saved into a mariahDB 10.2 database. The text,  to complicate matters, is in fact a combination of Regular Expressions and  a hybrid code invented by someone else.It can be used unchanged in another application as a text file - not PHP.  But it just text at the end of the day. I want to grab data  from this table, change it a small amount, and save it in a new table.

The problem is less so about changing the original data much, but more about SELECTING and saving data that is full of backslashes, single quotes, and double quotes to a new table  without it being changed when it is saved. Is there a simple way in PHP and MySQL to take text from a table and resave it exactly as it is  so the second table is not different from the the first?

For example the first table has the following in it.

`add list to list(%section,$plugin function("XpathPlugin.dll", "$Generic Xpath Parser", $document text, "//p[1]/a[@class=\'result-title hdrlnk\' and 1]", "outerhtml", "False"),"Don\'t Delete","Global")`

But if I put this into a variable and then INSERT or UPDATE  that to another table, MySQL seems to strip out the backslashes, or add backslashes and throw errors for incorrectly formatted SQL.

For instance `Don\'t Delete` becomes `Don't Delete` and in other examples  `\\` become `\`

In another case `?=\")"` loses the a backslash and becomes `?=")"`

I have tried dozens of combinations of PHP function to leave the text alone, such as addslashes(), htmlentities(), preg_replace(), various string substitution and nothing get the data back into the table the same way as it came out.

Does anyone have the trick to do this? I would call the function leave_my_text_alone(); !!

EDIT

To add a few things that did not do the trick to get a variable I could update into the database I tried

`$omnibotScript = addcslashes($omnibotScript,"'");`

I then found I need to do this twice to consider the backslash being removed from before the apostrophe in Don't Delete....or it would throw a MySQL parsing error..Doing it again fixed that. So then I had to put two backslashes back to have one removed. I then added this to consider a double backslash being reduced to single backslash.

```
$pattern = '/\\\\"/';
$replacement = '\\\\\\\"';
$omnibotScript = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $omnibotScript);
```

But the list went on.

Comment: would help if you'd post your code which doesn't work so we can elaborate.

Comment: I have added some of the problems, but they are numerous. In order to save a string that has been taken from MySQL, and save it back you have to double all the backslashes and then consider the backslashes that escaped the single quotes, double quotes. I suppose I need a regex that puts the string back into MySQL exactly how it came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use prepared statements.

If you use a prepared statement, MySQL will take care of all the escaping you need to get the string back into the table exactly as it came out of it. For example, using `MySQLi`:

```
$query = "SELECT s1 FROM t1";
if (!$result = $con->query($query)) {
    exit($con->error);
}
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$value = $row['s1'];

$query = "INSERT INTO t2(s1) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

The value of `s1` in `t2` will be *exactly* the same as the value in `t1`.

Comment: This sounds promising. I had read about prepared statements, this may well get me on my way. Will be testing.

Comment: @user2818170 prepared statements can save you a lot of hassles; they are well worth the small amount of extra effort to implement. I implemented this demo on my local server with the sample string from your question and it works exactly as it should; a `SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.s1 = t2.s1` brings up the row from both tables.

Comment: $value is my string right? Can I do some regex on $value between the  the two blocks of code and the new string will be held in t2 ? As mentioned above, I just need to change a small amount of the string and leave all the backslashes etc unchanged.

Comment: @user2818170 can you make a small demo on https://3v4l.org of what you are trying to do? But as long as you don't modify the section with backslashes it should be fine still

Comment: I will try to find time. Out of interest would mysqli::real_escape_string achieve the same thing ?

Comment: @user2818170 possibly... I generally steer clear of that function as it doesn't provide the protection against injection that you might hope for, but it might work for this particular case.

Comment: I have heard mysqli::real_escape_string is a last resort. Will be testing the prepared statement solution.

Comment: $omnibotScript = $link->real_escape_string($omnibotScript );  does work but this answer is better so I will mark it as correct